# Ansible playbook for windows server 2019 issue with GET-ADuser

Tags: powershell, ssh, ansible, active-directory

I am trying to run a community.windows.win_domain_user on ansible. My current playbook I am running is as followed.

```
---
- name: connect to windows server
  hosts: win
  connection: ssh
  gather_facts: no
  
  vars:
   ansible_connection: ssh
   ansible_shell_type: cmd

  tasks:
  - name: Ensure user bob is present with address information
    community.windows.win_domain_user:
     name: Bob.c
     firstname: Bob
     lastname: Carrender
     groups:
      - Users
     domain_username: testing.com\bob.c
     domain_password: SomePas2w0rd
     domain_server: testing.com
```

- The CSV file containing the updated AD server information is located on the Ubuntu machine.
- The host files on the Windows servers in the mesh need to be updated with the information from the CSV.
- The Ubuntu machine has access to all of the Windows servers in the mesh via SSH.
- The SSH connection between the Ubuntu machine and the Windows servers is authenticated using password fingerprints.
- The Ubuntu machine is able to run other Windows playbooks successfully.
- The Local Network Policy on the Windows servers has been updated to allow various encryption sessions to be enabled.

[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/icfPv.png)

I am trying to automate the process of updating the Active Directory (AD) servers on the host files of multiple servers within my mesh. I have a CSV file that contains the updated AD server information, and I want to use this information to update the host files on all of the servers in my mesh.

Comment: Based on the error, it sounds like you're not passing valid credentials (the `domain_username` and `domain_password` values)

Comment: I'm unsure if my playbook is allowing me to create new AD users or simply validating information. My assumption was that the playbook was intended to create a new AD user, but I'm not certain. Can anyone clarify whether this playbook is intended to create new AD users or if it has a different purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The module being used is only capable of verifying existing username information and does not have the ability to create new accounts.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).